Reflection coefficient formula

Formula reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient
Reflection coefficient is as above. I would like to know what does it mean physically and how did we ended up to this conclusion? I mean to be able to write this formula, we needed to observe some physical facts. What were these facts?

This is from a previous answer of mine. To understand reflections (and reflection coefficient) we can set up a thought experiment: -

Assume a cable (transmission-line or t-line) of characteristic impedance \$Z_0\$
At some distance away a resistor (\$Z_L\$) terminates the t-line
Assume a voltage (\$V_F\$) is applied at the start of the t-line
The current (\$I_F\$) that initially flows into the t-line equals \$V_F\$ divided by \$Z_0\$ (ohm's law)

When the voltage and accompanying current reach the end of the t-line there may be a violation of ohm's law if \$Z_L\$ does not equal \$Z_0\$. The process of fixing a violation uncovers the meaning of the reflection coefficient.
For instance, if \$Z_L\$ > \$Z_0\$ we have to mathematically: -

Make the voltage arriving at \$Z_L\$ a bit bigger and, at the same time...
Make the current arriving at \$Z_L\$ a bit smaller
Adjust voltage and current to force a ratio of \$Z_L\$ (make ohm's law work)
But, the adjustments have to "go somewhere" and, indeed they form a reflection
That reflection travels back up the line to the source

Algebraically we could say: -
$$\dfrac{V_F + \delta V_F}{I_F - \delta I_F} = Z_L$$
I've added a bit of voltage and, subtracted a bit of current. Mathematically it is like this: -
$$\dfrac{V_F}{I_F}\cdot \dfrac{1 + \delta}{1 - \delta} = Z_L\longrightarrow Z_0\cdot \dfrac{1 + \delta}{1 - \delta} = Z_L$$
$$\text{Hence,}\hspace{1cm}\delta Z_0 +\delta Z_L = Z_L - Z_0$$
$$\text{And,}\hspace{1cm}\delta = \dfrac{Z_L-Z_0}{Z_L+Z_0}$$
But, of course, we call \$\delta\$ by it's usual name (reflection coefficient) \$\Gamma\$. The symbol \$\delta\$ is just a device I invented to get through the thought experiment.
However, the important subtlety that prevents an ohm's law violation is the "bit" we add to voltage and the "bit" we subtract from current (\$\delta V_F\$ and \$\delta I_F\$).
If we examined their ratio we would find it is \$Z_0\$. This means that they can naturally flow (together) back into the transmission line because they have the perfectly correct ratio to do so and don't compound any ohm's law violation problems.
That is called a reflection and travels from load to source.
Clearly, if \$V_F\$ and \$I_F\$ were originally of a ratio that matched the load (\$Z_L\$) impedance, we wouldn't need to set up the algebra that figured out how to deal with the "extra" signals and, there would be no thoughts of violating ohm's law nor talk of reflections.

When \$Z_L\$ is an open circuit, we have to reflect the full applied voltage back to the source (in order to also return the full current) hence,

That reflected voltage superimposes itself on top of the incident voltage and,
For a short period of time we get twice the voltage at the end of the t-line
The action of doing that means there is no net current flowing into an open circuit
This is the conservation of ohm's law when an open circuit is encountered
I.e. there is a cancellation of currents flowing down the t-line to the load

What happens next depends on how the initial reflection is dealt with at the source end. If the source is a pure voltage (no series resistance), the initial reflection from the load gets fully reflected back to the load end and, things carry-on sloshing around indefinitely.

From Wikipedia.

This is the coefficient at the load. The reflection coefficient can also be measured at other points on the line. The magnitude of the reflection coefficient in a lossless transmission line is constant along the line (as are the powers in the forward and reflected waves). However its phase will be shifted by an amount dependent on the electrical distance
ϕ from the load.

This means that we can calculate the "incident wave" and the "reflected wave" on a transmission line.
On a simple transmission line, there are two waves that circulate (one from generator to load, and another (from load to generator).
If the line is not "adapted", this can continue until "reflections" are too litlle to matter.
To discover this formula, you must write the equations around a physical transmission line.
It says also that if ZL = Zo, the reflection coefficient is equal to zero.
Then we have only a circulating wave from "generator to load". No "return" wave.
