scattering matrix of a dipole
Consider the following dipole:

I want to calculate the s-matrix of this circuit:
i think it is \$ b = S a \iff S = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{z_L - 1}{z_L +1}\$ with \$ z_L = \frac{Z_L}{Z_o} \$
But according to @AndyAka's answer the coefficient of reflection doesnt have a conjugate on the characteristic impedance as if they assumed its a real quantity, not a complex one.
EDIT
Here is my approach, so i think the diagram is just an abstracted version of this circuit -correct me if im wrong - :



Finally : \$S = \frac{b}{a} = \frac{V_r}{V_i} = \frac{Z_0}{Z_0 ^*} \cdot \frac{Z_L - Z_0^*}{Z_L + Z_0}\$

That looks like the reflection coefficient to me. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

yes @Andyaka the reflection coefficient as seen from dipole

Are you saying you want to derive the reflection coefficient mathematically i.e. you are looking for a proof? Maybe this will help if you are: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/725837/reflection-coefficient-formula/725843#725843

I want first to see if my answer is true, if not i would appreciate a correct answer @Andyaka I had seen the coefficient of reflection but why is it $-Z_{o} $ and not $ -Z_{o}^* $ the conjugate of the characteristic impedance?

Does the link help?

Yes sir Andy, i will put effort to digest that information , i will reply back if i dont understand it. Infinite thanks @Andyaka

@Andyaka Hello sir, have a look at my edited part

Yes, I have assumed a standard resistive impedance (as you would see for any cable above 100 kHz).

Infinite thanks sir, i had upvoted ur answer in the former link @Andyaka
